# One-to-one and Many-to-one relationships with the same pair of models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Profile model and Photo model. Each profile has photos (One-to-many relationship) and a profile photo (One-to-one relationship). When I try to do this on django I get the error `NameError: name 'Photo' is not defined`
 because I'm referencing the model before it's defined.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    profile_photo = models.OneToOneField(
        Photo,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

class Photo(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(primary_key=True, upload_to='photos/')
```

A possible solution could be using a boolean field on Photo to specify if it's a profile photo or not, but I think that's inefficient because I'd have to query all photos of the profile and make a loop to find the profile photo. Are there a better solution for that?

Comment: Well you refer to a class that still needs to be constructed, use a string (so `'Photo'` instead of `Photo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* the fact that you create two relations. Although it can cause some trouble (and therefore you better for example define `related_name`s, etc.), the issue is that you **refer to a class before it is constructed**.

Indeed, Python reads files from top to bottom. In your file you define a class `Profile` with a reference to `Photo`, but at that point, there is no variable named `Photo` yet (whether that is a class or not is irrelevant, at least for Python).

You can solve this by using a string literal instead, Django will later, when all models are loaded, do the linking itself. So you can write:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, blank=False)
    profile_photo = models.OneToOneField(
        'Photo',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

That being said, it is not entirely clear to me why you define two relations: Django automatically adds a reverse relation, so without specifying `profile = ...` in the `Photo` class, Django will automatically have added such `profile` relation. This will then work by using a `JOIN` (and querying the database in "reverse"). Unless the two relations are two *different* ways to combine the two models, it is better to use one relation, since this will avoid *data duplication*.

Comment: I think I get it, but I think I still have to have `profile = ...` in the `Photo` because it's a One-to-many relationship, the profile have multiple photos.

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade: ah, in that case it is indeed a use case for two relations. But in that case I would advice to name these propery (perhaps rename `profile=...` to `author=...` or something similar).